# In webdriverios, how to select the last element with the same classname?

Tags: javascript, html, webdriver-io

I have multiple elements with the same class name and I want to select the last one.

I tried the following method but they do not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const elem = $('.example')[-1]
const elem = $('.example[-1]')
const elem = $('.example').last()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) CSS pseudo-selector:

```
const elem = $('.example:last-child')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also `:last-of-type` might be useful :) For example:

```js
// Get the last <p> element
const elem = $('p:last-of-type')
console.log(elem)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <h1>A Title</h1>
  <p>Paragraph 1.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3.</p>
  <img src="...">
</article>
```